# addClass/removeClass based on selected items data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, removeclass

I'm a little stuck here. I have a `ul` menu of links. When a user selects from this list, I'm calling up content from another page with ajax. I want to grab a data attribute (`data-flag`) from the selected anchor and add that attribute as a class to the div that holds the ajax content (`#fourteen`). The adding class piece is working fine. However, when a new item is selected from the `ul` menu, I can't seem to remove the other classes from the content div. With each click, it just adds more classes.

Here's my code.

```
<ul id="langtest" class="tp_lang2">
 <li><a href="http://myurl.com/14-languages" data-flag="us" data-lang="English">English</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://myurl.com/zh/14-languages" data-flag="cn" data-lang="Chinese (Simplified)">中文(简体)</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://myurl.com/nl/14-languages" data-flag="nl" data-lang="Dutch">Nederlands</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://myurl.com/fr/14-languages" data-flag="fr" data-lang="French">Français</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="fourteen" class="cn">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="main-content">Content being served up here.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

    <script>

     jQuery("ul#langtest li a").click(function() {

        jQuery('#fourteen').load($(this).attr("href") + " #content");
        jQuery('#fourteen').removeClass.not(this).attr("data-flag");
        jQuery('#fourteen').addClass($(this).attr("data-flag"));
        return false;
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove all class in the element like so :

```
// remove all class
jQuery('#fourteen').removeClass();
// then add class name with data flag selected anchor only
jQuery('#fourteen').addClass($(this).attr("data-flag"));
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/fcghtf9k/)(*inspect element to see the class actually added & removed*)

Answer (score 1):

On dynamically added element you have to use `delegate` `event` binding.

```
jQuery(document).on("click","ul#langtest li a",function() {

    jQuery('#fourteen').load($(this).attr("href") + " #content");
    //also change your removeClass code
    jQuery('#fourteen').removeClass();
    jQuery('#fourteen').addClass($(this).attr("data-flag"));
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `removeClass` seems not perfect. Do it like below.

```
jQuery('#fourteen').removeClass();
```

Comment: Thanks Azim, I got this working with Norlihazmey's answer. I tried yours as well but got the same result. It only added classes, didn't remove them.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry to misunderstood you. However, I've updated my answer. @Chris